# How to display live video in picturebox using opencvsharp?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

This is what I am trying

```
CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(0);

for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
{
    IplImage src = cap.QueryFrame();
    video.Image = src.ToBitmap();
    CvWindow.WaitKey(5);
}
```

But when the form is displayed it only shows last captured frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the application time to display each frame separately. Try to call [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) in your loop.